# Python - Nested dict, versus hashing a tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm wondering what are the pros/cons of nested dicts versus hashing a tuple in Python?

The context is a small script to assign "workshops" to attendees at a conference.

Each workshop has several attributes (e.g. week, day, subject etc.). We use four of these attributes in order to assign workshops to each attendee - i.e. each delegate will also have a week/day/subject etc.

Currently, I'm using a nested dictionary to store my workshops:

```
workshops = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(dict))))

with open(input_filename) as input_file:
    workshop_reader = csv.DictReader(input_file, dialect='excel')

    for row in workshop_reader:
        workshops[row['Week ']][row['Stream']][row['Strand']][row['Day']] = row

return workshops
```

I can then use the above data-structure to assign each attendee their workshop.

The issue is later, I need to iterate through every workshop, and assign an ID (this ID is stored in a different system), which necessitates unwrapping the structure layer by layer.

First question - is there some other way of creating a secondary index to the same values, using a string (workshop name) as a key? I.e. I'd still have the four-level nested dicts, but I could also search for individual entries based on just a name.

Secondly - how can I achieve a similar effect using tuples as the key? Are there any advantages you can think of using this approach? Would it be much cleaner, or easier to use? (This whole unwrapping this is a bit of a pain, and I don't think it's very approachable).

Or are there any other data structures that you could recommend that might be superior/easier to access/manipulate?

Thanks,
Victor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Workshop(object):
  def __init__(self, week, stream, strand, day, name):
    self.week = week
    self.stream = stream
    self.day = day
    self.strand = strand
    self.name = name

...
for row in workshop_reader:
  workshops['name'] = Workshop(...)
```

That is only **if the name is the unique attribute** of the workshops (that is, no workshops with repeating names).
Also, you'll be able to easily assign an ID to each Workshop object in the workshops dictionary.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a named tuple since it is just data?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point aeter =). I should have thought of that...lol.

And I suppose I can just create a dict of Workshops, to faciliate quick lookup? However, how do I traverse the hierarchy then? For example, before I could navigate to the first layer to get all Workshops in Week 1, then unwrap the next layer to get all Workshops in Week 1, Stream 1 etc. Is it still possible to do some navigation using classes?

Comment: Basically, if I go class-based, is there an easy way to list all the Workshops for a given Week/Strand/Stream - assuming that Week/Strand/Stream are instance attributes in the class?

Comment: You can list them by iterating through the items of the dictionary, e.g. for Workshops for week 1: for k,v in workshops.iteritems(): if v.week == 1: print v.name (which may or may not be fast enough for you). The dictionary {"name":Workshop} is best for searching a Workshop through its name, as you asked for.

Comment: If you want to be able to make many different searches on them, and/or you have a lot of data, you may want to consider using a relational database such as SQLite.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, if you need to nest dictionaries, you should use classes instead. Nested dictionaries gets complicated to keep track of when you are debugging. With classes you can tell different types of dictionaries apart, so it gets easier. :)

Comment: With classes, I'm not sure how I can descend down the hierarchy though - before, with nested Dicts, I could unwrap the first layer to get all Workshops in Week 1, then unwrap one of the dicts within that to get a particular stream etc. Not sure how I can do that with just Class Workshop though...hmm...

Comment: @victorhooi: You descend with attribute access. So instead of a adict['foo'] = {} you do anobject.foo = anotehrobject()

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: Hmm, I think I'm going to have to rethink how I store these. Because it's not like "Weeks" will store a list of "workshops", it will store a dict (?) or some other collection, for each stream. And each stream will have another collection for each strand. And only then will we get to the actual workshops. Should I create class Week, class Stream, class Strand - or is there a better way?

Comment: @victorhooi: No, that seems reasonable, but only you can know what objects to have. :)

Comment: Well - actually, all I need is to be able to pull up all the workshops for a given week, or a given week/strand, or a given week/strand/stream etc. - something O(1) would be good.

Comment: @victorhooi: in that case, load it into a SQL database.